# Decrypt files in a VB6 installer. like file.ex_

Tags: c#, installation

I need to decrypt the files that are on a VB6 install package. Once files are in the installer are like `file.bm_` and when I decrypted this file, this file is named `file.bmp`. I try with the program win.rar and saw recognized as encrypted files and decrypted well, but I don't know how to do this from an application in `c#`.

Thank you.

Comment: They are just compressed, not encrypted.  You could try to decompress with GZip, they did not use anything proprietary on them as I recall.

Comment: [If memory serves](http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/d10share/installr.zip), they are compressed with the [Lempel-Ziv algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel-Ziv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, had to find these.

If GZip doesnt work and you need a last resort.  There are some DOS files bzip.exe, bunzip.exe and a win32 version that you can still likely find somewhere on the net.  Mine are dated 2007 but they still work as far as I know (last I think I needed them was on XP 64, 2011).   The upside is that they handle several compression formats.

Like I said, a last resort.